# Can I access a voice memo file that's attached to an email stuck in my iPhone's outbox?

Tags: ms-office, ios, voice

Is there a way to access a file that's attached to a message stuck in my iPhone's Outlook outbox, unsent?

I attempted to send two large voice memos to an email recipient as attachments, but the server rejected the email (I suspect due to the size of the attachments) and it remains unsent on my iPhone.

[The original voice memos in my voice memo utility have since been damaged (my fault, long story) and I'd really like to retrieve these two files if possible.]

Comment: not sure if it works for sound files, but with, for instance, a pdf, you can attempt to open it & the phone will ask you in what app. This may then copy it over to that app's filespace & let you drag it out from iTunes. [completely untested, but I've done similar with other file types]

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a commercial product, [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), can access your iPhone's file system and retrieve almost anything. I believe it has a free trial mode, too.

I'm a satisfied, licensed customer, and have user iExplorer to recover important files otherwise unobtainable. It can even restore data from iTunes backups!

Answer (score 0):

iExplorer will NOT retrieve the trimmed away part of a trimmed Voice Memo on/from iPhone. Once the iOS iPhone/iTouch file was trimmed and saved as original its gone forever! unfortunately. I just had this experience. I trimmed a voice memo after I sent it off in Email thinking it will be sent, but it didnt sent because it was about 42MB file size.. a recording of 1 hour and 14 minutes. Now its stuck in Outbox, and the original file is no more in Voice Memo.